# RMarkdown knitting error papaja apa6 - rmdfiltr add wordcount filter

Tags: r, r-markdown, papaja

I get the following error when knitting papaja::apa6_pdf docs. I'm running R version 3.6.2 with macOS Mojave (10.14.6) on my MacBook Pro. Any ideas?

```
Error in rmdfiltr::add_wordcount_filter(args, report = "warn") : 
  unused argument (report = "warn")
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> pdf_pre_processor
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused by incompatible versions of `papaja` and `rmdfiltr`. Updating `papaja` (e.g. `devtools::install_github("crsh/papaja@devel")`) should fix this issue.